# Traces of lines in the QGraphicsView on using paint method

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I am using QGraphicsView and added one rectangle item(It's a separate class). Now In Rectangle class I am drawing a point on one line of rectangle using paint method. But If I try to Increase the size of that line the point leaves trace on graphics view. Can some one please tell me how to solve this and remove traces.
For removing traces of line I have used this->prepareGeometryChange();
but this function is not working for the point. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reimplement the method `boundingRect` of your class `Rectangle`

```
QRectF Rectangle::boundingRect() const {
...
}
```

To take into account of the extra space for the point